# SqlException: Connection Timeout Expired in Startup.cs thrown immediately (without waiting for the timeout period)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.2

I have ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC Web app, with Entity Framework and built-in identity provider.

On application startup I access database (through the identity provider, which uses EF).

When I open the website first time after longer period of inactivity, it takes ca 30 seconds and then I get an error:

> SqlException: Connection Timeout Expired

That is ok, because I'm using Azure database with automatic shutdown on inactivity, so it probably takes longer time to start.

But when I refresh the browser I get the timeout exception immediately, as if EF was trying to reuse the connection that just timed out. Can you explain why and how to fix it?

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionStr")),
         ServiceLifetime.Scoped, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

    using (IServiceScope scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<UserRolesConfig>>();

        roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName).Wait(); //this throws the exception
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, object providerInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling, string accessToken)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, bool buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.FirstOrDefault_<TSource>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in First.cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+TaskResultAsyncEnumerable<T>+Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in Select.cs
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncIterator<TSource>.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in AsyncIterator.cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor<T>+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery<TResult>(QueryContext queryContext, Func<QueryContext, IAsyncEnumerable<TResult>> compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger<Query> logger, Type contextType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager<TRole>.RoleExistsAsync(string roleName)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `optionsLifetime` to `Scoped`, which is default, or just remove the 2 lifetime settings and use default?

Comment: Im going to try it, but I havent read anywhere that DBContextOptions are related to db connection

Comment: @Liero Most likly you are missing indentity configuration `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();` and then `app.UseAuthentication();` take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio